# Freeform field staus option?

Tags: solspace-freeform, checkbox

I have a checkbox field in my form where the values are from another channels title field.

What I would like is to have only entries with status="open" to appear in the checkbox group.  My code below however, is not working.  Is this possible?

```
{freeform:field:assigned_editor
                attr:id="238"
                attr:class="radio"
                status="open"}
```

Thanks!

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest embedding your freeform code and then passing a variable with for status something like this.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}

some code here

{embed="template_group/freeform_form" entries_status="{status}"}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in the freeform embed code you would do this:

```
{freeform:field:assigned_editor
                attr:id="238"
                attr:class="radio"
                status="{embed:entries_status}"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.  I don't think the freeform:field can handle a status variable.  Darn!  I figure there must be a way to do this though!  I'll keep on it.  This is weird.  I don't think solspace would make a product that doesn't allow the edit feature to utilize one of its strengths (leading fields values from a channel).  At least I would hope not.